# What software, tools and API solutions whe have for SOA today?

Tags: java, soa, code-reuse

my studies team is projecting SOA system with automated composite of services. There is meany papers about abstract SOA but we can't find about practical way. We wants to fit in java standards for SOA and don't want to write from scratch what is good to reuse today.

There is meany tools like protege and jena to manipulate ontologies but should we write from scratch for example ontology broker (owl server) or projecting own WSDL API for every part of system (are there some patterns to reuse)?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question without using buzzwords from a Gartner white paper on architecture?

Comment: I rewrite my question. This is not my native language so sorry if misunderstood your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a good, open source SOA architecture in java then I would take a look at [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/home.html). It has a stellar component back end based on [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) and an excellent service bus based on OSGi.